# No module named PyQt5

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

I'm trying to create a simple program using python and PyQt. I cannot run my work because of this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "pyqt_first.py", line 2, in <module>
  from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, uic
ModuleNotFoundError: No module name 'PyQt5'
```

Here is my code:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, uic

qtCreatorFile = "tax_calc.ui"

Ui_MainWindow, QtBaseClass = uic.loadUiType(qtCreatorFile)

class MyApp(QtGui.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
def __init__(self):
    QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
    Ui_MainWindow.__init__(self)
    self.setupUi(self)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyApp()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: How did you install PyQt? and what is your OS?

Comment: Windows 7. Got the installer here https://sourceforge.net/projects/pyqt/

Comment: I have installed python 3.6 by the way.

Comment: What version of PyQt5 and how have you installed it?

Comment: PyQt5-5.6-gpl-Py3.5-Qt5.6.0-x32-2 This one. I'd just downloaded it and installed. Is it just fine? Sorry I'm just a beginner here.

Comment: According to the name of the file I download is for python3.5: yQt5-5.6-gpl- **Py3.5** -Qt5.6.0-x32-2

Comment: Oh thanks! I didn't noticed it. Anyway i already installed the compatible PyQt for mine. It's now working. Thanks!